# Why do we think that the dark sector is simpler?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, observable-universe

Matter makes up roughly $5\%$ of the Universe while dark matter makes up roughly $25\%$. For matter and radiation, we have a complicated Standard model with many generations of fermions and various force mediators. Given this fact isn't it a wishful thinking that dark matter is made up of only one particle? People try that because that's the simplest thing to try.

*But in absence of any definitive observational or experimental signature how justified is that simplified version of the single component dark matter models?*

Comment: Given the need to have at least two population of dark matter to explain cosmological observations I suspect most people are assuming a non-trivial dark sector. But given that few populations are needed there doesn't seem to be a reason to assume a lot of complexity yet.

Answer (score 5):

One of my favourite dark matter theories is [mirror dark matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3965): the entire dark sector has exactly the same physics as ours: there are dark electrons, dark photons, dark protons etc interacting with each other. This is exactly as complex as our physics. However, the theory then needs to find a creative way of explaining the relative smoothness of dark matter halos compared to our galaxies (basically lots of supernovas keeping it mostly plasma). This is *conceptually* simple, even though the dark matter world is/will eventually be just as complicated as our world.

(I don't actually *believe* there is mirror dark matter, but it is a fun concept and illustrates my point.)

The problem here is that "simple" [is not a simple concept](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simplicity/). It might mean that we want to use the theory that adds the fewest extra things - but does that refer to extra laws of nature, extra symmetries, extra particle types, extra interactions? It might also mean that the overall theory should be as little arbitrary as possible - each extra thing should ideally fit or explain as many unsolved issues as possible (this is why we assume dark matter is behind both galaxy rotation curves and cosmic structure formation rather than assuming two separate unknowns). Mirror dark matter does pretty well on the first approach, just double physics, but it does not do that well on the second since there is little new explanatory power. Axions were proposed as a solution to another problem but could *also* be a dark matter candidate, so they do much better on the second meaning.

I assume one important constraint on dark matter complexity is that back when the universe was hot enough presumably matter and dark matter interacted, and the number of degrees of freedom of the dark matter would have affected baryogenesis and other properties of the big bang we can today measure. If there was a zillion degrees of dark matter freedom that would have left a thermodynamic mark on the universe.

Comment: the problem with your mirror hypothesis is that there should also be dark galaxies and clusters, in this mirror universe overlapping the physical, why would they stick to halos around real galaxies?

Comment: @annav - The explanation in that theory is that there was more dark matter hydrogen, producing a lot of early supernovas heating the gas into hot plasma halos. Our side is much cooler and sparse, so it condensed into galaxies early while the dark side has not fully done so yet.

Comment: thanks, I will have a look at the link you give. I would think that the extra dimensions of string theories might fit such model ,

Comment: see this  https://www.nature.com/news/2005/050829/full/news050829-18.html

Comment: @annav - be aware that these DM theories are not the same as the one I discussed. But it makes a good philosophy of science exercise to see how they fit into the simplicity types I discuss.

Answer (score 4):

Why do we keep dark matter models simple? It's partly because science progresses best if, when we realise current theory is missing something we try the simplest way to address that first; if even that turns out to be empirically wrong we can add further complexity, but if we add complexity prematurely it can harm falsifiability (e.g. due to having more tunable parameters).

It's also partly because the models you've seen are motivated by something other than the dark matter problem. Often, we don't dream up models purely to explain away a surprise; we find that a single thing makes sense of multiple concerns. In this case, we have other motives for supersymmetry with $R$-parity conservation, but the lightest supersymmetric partner (LSP) is a natural dark matter candidate.